# Do something when google.maps api has finished loading

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have set a google api autocomplete in my project and it works fine, but I have searched for and event that allows me to do somethings when this api finishes loading position after writing something in the input text, here is some  code that I hope it can help you understand what I want to do

```
   function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});


    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  autocomplete.addListener(map,'tilesloaded', function(){  alert('sgsg');});
  }
```

I used 'tilesloaded' event but I'm not sure if it is the right event to use

thank you!

Comment: If you want to do something when the **map** finishes loading, then you should add the event handler on the Map object, not on the Autocomplete object.

Comment: not when the map has finished, but when the api has finished displaying list of locations depending on what is written

Comment: There's not such event in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete). You would probably need to use the `AutoCompleteService`, which means tracking user input and building the select list yourself...

Comment: I'll see what I can do